# creating view models for models with one to many relationship in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I Created two models name as Company and Agent and There should be a one to many relationship between them because each company could have many Agents but each agent is related to one company. These Models are as follow:

```
    Public class Company
    {
    Public int ComapnyId {get;set;}
    Public String CompanyName{get;set;}
    Public String tell{get;set;}
    Public String Address{get;set;}
    Public virtual ICollection<Agent> Agents {get;set;}
    }

    Public Class Agent
    {
    Public int AgentId{get;set;}
    public string FName{get;set;}
    public string LName{get;set;}
    public string Mobile{get;set;}
    public int? CompanyId{get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public virtual Company company{get;set;} 
    }
```

then I create View Models as follow, but I am not sure I defined them correctly to satisfy my goal.

```
     public Class CompanyViewModel
     {
     Public int ComapnyId {get;set;}
     Public String CompanyName{get;set;}
     Public String tell{get;set;}
     Public String Address{get;set;}
     Public List<AgentViewModel> AgentsName {get;set;}
     }

     Public AgentViewModel
     {
     Public int AgentId{get;set;}
     public string FName{get;set;}
     public string LName{get;set;}
     public string Mobile{get;set;}
     public int? CompanyId{get;set;}
     [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
     public string CompanyName{get;set;}
     }
```

Indeed I want when user wants to create an agent display him all companies in a drop down list. I have so many question about it but the first one is two properties of

```
      Public List<AgentViewModel> AgentsName {get;set;} and 
      public string CompanyName{get;set;}
```

defined correctly in viewmodels for my goal?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you are not doing this correctly. So what you have successfully done is create two new classes that are basically duplicates of your model classes, and just changed the names to include the word viewmodel

In this instance what you should be doing is just passing the view a new Agent model and setting a distinct list of companies (cast into selectListItems) in the viewBag to use as the select drop down to set the value of the CompanyId on your Agent model.

With your exact need as you described, there isn't justification for creating the view models.